# Is it possible to create simple slopes with quadratic variable?

Tags: interaction

Interactions are often explained by means of simples slopes. A simples slope is the effect of X1 on Y, at a specific value of X2.

But what if the variable X1 is a non-linear? Is it possible to describe the relationship between (X1/X1^2) on Y, at a specific value of X2 with simples slopes?

My intuition tells me that it is not possible. Are there other ways to describe a moderation with a quadratic term involved?

Comment: Yes it is possible, I've never seen someone actually use it.

Comment: @user2974951, do you know how? Or do you have a reference?

Comment: Any example of non-simple slope?

Comment: Are you trying to interpret a specific equation, such as the coefficient in front of an interaction term from a regression equation?

Comment: As always, just take a finite difference or a derivative.